# How to remove schema name from query after generate service in wso data service server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm using the function "Generate" on WSO2 Data Services Server in order to create "automatically" web services from a certain DB schema. Once the web service are generated, their queries include the schema name as prefix in the SQL code, for example:

```
 SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME
```

Is there any way to generate the web services without including the schema name in the queries "automatically"?

I know it's possible to do it manually(going one by one service and deleting the schema name from each query), but it takes too long for my case because I'm generating web services for a lot of tables.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment if you create data service by Generate feature you will get the SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME in the data service (if there are any schema's associated with the data source).